# move_uploaded_file warning

Tags: php

I am encountering the following error message saying:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/computer-science1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory....
```

while trying to move a file to a directory. above code provided.
I have also enabled the uploaded file in FileZilla to be writable and executable, is there another way of solving particular problem?
Thank you.

```
<?php
$upload_url = "uploads/" . $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];

$filename = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $upload_url);

$conn = mysqli_connect("yourhost", "username", "password", "databasename");

$sql = "INSERT INTO images (image_url, image_title) VALUES     ('$upload_url','$filename') ";

$imageresults = mysqli_query( $conn,$sql );

$sql = "SELECT image_url, image_title from images";

if ($imageresults = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql )) {

while ( $currentimage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($imageresults ) ) {

echo "<div><img src= '" . $currentimage['image_url'] . "'  

                        width='200' height='200'/><br/>" .

$currentimage['image_title']  . "</div>";

}

}

} catch( Exception $e ) {
echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

Comment: Try `$upload_url = "./uploads/" . $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];`

Comment: hi, thank for responding, however it is still not working.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but you can never be too sure. Is this PHP file in the parent directory of `/uploads/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script must be in a directory which contains a sub-directory, `uploads/`, which is writeable.

It seems as if you are attempting to move the file from its temporary location to a folder (`uploads/`) that either doesn't exist or that the script is unable to write to.

Answer (score 0):

When you've got this message :

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/computer-science1.jpg): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory....

It means that the location of the file or the location of the destination directory is not good. Maybe you can check your link path of "uploads/computer-science1.jpg"

You can use a test to check it :

```
if(move_uploaded_file($yourFile, $yourlocation)) {
    echo 'Good ! ';
} else {
    exit('Error !');
}
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I've edited it so it looks like more of an answer now :)